# How to train only front part of a neural network?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm using pytorch to train part of the network. For example, I have a model structure

```
hidden1 = Layer1(x)
hidden2 = Layer2(hidden1)
out = Layer3(hidden2)
```

If I want to train Layer3 only, I can use

```
hidden1 = Layer1(x)
hidden2 = Layer2(hidden1).detach()
out = Layer3(hidden2)
```

However, this time I want to train Layer1 only. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`detach` will not really "freeze" your layer.
If you don't want to train a layer, you should use `requires_grad=False` instead.

For example:

```
hidden2.weight.requires_grad = False
hidden2.bias.requires_grad = False
```

Then to unfreeze, you do the same with `requires_grad=True`.

Comment: OMG, I've known the wrong answer so far. Thank you very much!